# $pager_total_items giving wrong results count in custom search module

Tags: 7, search, paging

I am not too sure what happens but in my custom search module, the `$GLOBALS['pager_total_items']` count is wrong on the first page.

For example, I search for a term and it will display: *Showing 1 - 10 of 77 results* and the pager shows 9 pages (when it should show only 8).

Then if I click the pager to go to page 2 (or any other page) the display changes to: *Showing 11 - 12 of 12 results* and the pager now shows 2 pages (which is right).

In my `TEMPLATE_preprocess_search_results` function, I use `$GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0]` to get the total number of results.

Any idea what could go wrong? Or should I post my complete module code?